# Create a security group in VPC using boto ec2 connection object

Tags: boto

I am trying to create a security group using boto ec2 connection object. Security group is getting created successfully but it is creating in ec2, but I would like create it in the VPC. Below is the code snippet

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
from sys import argv
connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
create = connection.create_security_group('test', 'Testing')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I should be using boto.vpc instead of boto.ec2. See the below code used to create a security group in VPC.

```
import boto
import boto.vpc
from sys import argv
connection = boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
create = connection.create_security_group('testing1', 'testing1', vpc_id='vpc-1234abc56')
print create, create.id, create.name
```

Comment: You should be fine to create with `boto.ec2` directly: `connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1'); create = connection.create_security_group('testing1', 'testing1', vpc_id='vpc-1234abc56')`, not require module `boto.vpc`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [boto doc for vpc](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/vpc.html#module-boto.vpc) you can tell that, although you are creating a boto.vpc.VPCConnection object, you are still creating connections to ec2, and there is actually no difference between these two methods for creating security groups.